# Basic modal logic - □(A ⊃ B) ⊃ (□A ⊃ □B)

Tags: logic

I've learned (on this forum) that in modal logic □(A V B) is not equivalent to (□A V □B). However, I was wondering whether this conflicts with the fact that (as far as I know)

□(A ⊃ B) ⊃ (□A ⊃ □B)

is a logical truth in modal logic.

Is there a conflict between these two facts? If no, could someone explain why?

Comment: Why *would* there be a conflict between these two facts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no conflict.  It may help you to look at it this way: if you express $\Box A \supset \Box B$ in terms of disjunction, you get $\Diamond \neg A \vee \Box B$.  Then you can read the sentence as "if $A \supset B$ is necessary, then either $\neg A$ is possible, or else $B$ is necessary.

$\Box(A \vee B)$ and $(\Box A) \vee (\Box B)$ are not equivalent because, even though neither $A$ nor $B$ may be necessary, it may be that their disjunction  is necessary.